# Best way to mock methods to main:Object?

Tags: ruby, inspec

We use the [inspec](https://community.chef.io/tools/chef-inspec) framework a lot.

It encourages code such as the following, and we have a lot of it:

### Sample Code

`rock_critic/controls.rb` from https://docs.chef.io/inspec/inputs/#a-simple-example:

```rb
# Set a default value for an input.  This is optional.
input('amplifier_max_volume', value: 10)

control 'Big Rock Show' do
  describe input('amplifier_max_volume') do    # This line reads the value of the input
    it { should cmp 11 } # The UK'S LOUDEST BAND
  end
end
```

### Input File

`input.yml`:

```yaml
amplifier_max_volume: 11
```

### Sample Execution

This would be executed as:

```
inspec exec rock_critic --input-file input.yml
```

### Issue

We would like to run this code with a variety of scenarios (e.g. list of pets from different sources, like files or created at runtime), using regular Ruby instead of the `inspec` wrapper.  i.e., `ruby rock_critic/controls.rb`

But if you do that, this is what you get:

### Error

```
$ ruby ./controls/controls.rb                                                                                                                           12:14:45
./controls/controls.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `input' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
$
```

So, perhaps I got the title or vocabulary wrong, but
what's the best way to mock a method like `input()`, which is defined globally (`main:Object`)?

Ideally, we'd like to have a separate test (`describe`, `it`, etc.) and pass in a variety of inputs to `input()`.

I've tried mixins and stuff like that, but it never quite works. Is there a good example?  We're probably doing something wrong.

Hope that's a better explanation, thank you!

### Hack

The hack I've been using is monkey-patching `Object`.

```rb
    require 'minitest/autorun'


    input_hash = {
      'amplifier_max_volume' => 12
    }


      Object.define_method(:input) { |key, **opts| input_hash[key] }

      require_relative 'rock_critic/controls.rb'
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem quite right and it's not easy to supply different values for `input()`.

Comment: I see no indication that `input` is defined against `Object`. It appears to be defined for `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup`. I am unclear on exactly what you hope to accomplish though, so if you could add a bit more detail that would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Python and Ruby had a baby.

Comment: @engineersmnky: i added more details to the issue, hope it helps!

Comment: You need `let` statements, before blocks, or shared examples. Your #input method isn't defined in your provided code, and no reason why you should expect an undefined method to yield anything but a NoMethodError. Add a test to check `defined? :input` in your test scope, and that will be the failing test that guides you towards an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're facing an issue because `input()` is a method provided by the InSpec DSL and not a global function in Ruby.
when you try to run the code with Ruby directly, it's unable to recognize `input()`.  A possible workaround could be to define a mock method in the Kernel module or use the actual `inspec` command to test the real behavior of your code.